# Codeigniter Static Wrapper for APC

Tags: php, codeigniter, apc

I wish to create a Static wrapper API for getting and setting values from the APC cache. 
I'm new to CodeIgniter. The examples on [CodeIgniter's page](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html) use $this to load the cache driver, which cannot work within a static function. 
Is there a way to load the driver statically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether It works or not. But just try like following:

```
$this->load->driver('some_parent');
```

And in the static function that you want to use the driver:

```
CI =& get_instance();
CI->some_parent->function();
```

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks! Also found that Ellis labs also recommends the same approach: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html